# Shopify- need to create a webhook

Tags: xml, shopify, webhooks

I need to create a web-hook which will be used to post the xml data to a repository.

The xml format should be like:

```
<Order OrderID="xxxx" AffiliateID="xxxxxx">
<ShipToName>Bob Sanders</ShipToName>           
<ShipToContact>Bob Sanders</ShipToContact>
<ShipToName2></ShipToName2>        
<AddressLine1>21 N. Long St.</AddressLine1>        
<AddressLine2>Unit A</AddressLine2>
<AddressLine3></AddressLine3>
<City>Barrington Hills</City>                        
<Country>US</Country>                  
<State>Il</State>      
<Province></Province>  
<Zip>60010</Zip>
<Email>madman@gmail.com</Email>
<Phone>7086639935</Phone>
<SpecialInstructions></SpecialInstructions>
<SpecialInstructions2></SpecialInstructions2>
```

Which currently is something like:

```
    <order>
<buyer-accepts-marketing type="boolean">true</buyer-accepts-marketing>
<cancel-reason nil="true"/>
<cancelled-at type="dateTime" nil="true"/>
<cart-token>6343c2a1ec2e675202ad9fdccb8fe862</cart-token>
<checkout-token>c62fcb629ce1df6a7202be1e4f34f237</checkout-token>
<closed-at type="dateTime" nil="true"/>
<confirmed type="boolean">true</confirmed>
<created-at type="dateTime">2014-11-24T23:22:22-07:00</created-at>
<currency>USD</currency>
<email>kads@hfi.com</email>
<financial-status>pending</financial-status>
<fulfillment-status nil="true"/>
<gateway>Cash on Delivery (COD)</gateway>
<id type="integer">282488743</id>
<landing-site>/</landing-site>
<location-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
<name>#SH1001</name>
<note nil="true"/>
<number type="integer">1</number>
```

I need to change the node names and grab only few required nodes not all of them.
I can't understand where to start from.

To better understand the situation here are the urls:

1. https://shibumi-home.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml [XML that needs to be modified]
2. http://divinepnc.com/a/webhooks-shopify/a.xml       [How it should be]

I am not asking to provide the exact code for the situation, all I'm asking is how should I be proceeding.

Many Thanks

Comment: Just parse the XML that is sent from Shopify and then put the XML file you need from those parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You can create a Webhook from the admin panel in the shopify, under notifications tab and point it to the url where you want to post the data(xml in my case, you can chose json also).

**2.** Then to grab to shopify-xml I used the following code, which gets stored on the server as "timber.xml".

Below is the example code snippet:

```
$webhookContent = "";
$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook,18920);
}
fclose($webhook);
//error_log($webhookContent);
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/a/webhooks-shopify/timber.xml","wb");
fwrite($fp,$webhookContent);
fclose($fp);
```

**3.** For converting the grabbed shopify-xml to the desired-xml, I used [PHP DOM
    LIBRARY](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Below is the example code snippet:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load('timber.xml');
$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;
//this gives you a list of elements by tag name
$order_number = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('order-number')->item(0);
$order_number_val = $order_number->textContent;

$shipping_address = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('shipping-address')->item(0);
$shipping_address = $shipping_address->lastChild;
$shipping_address = $shipping_address->previousSibling;
$shipping_address = $shipping_address->previousSibling;
$shipping_address_val = $shipping_address->textContent;

$address1 = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('shipping-address')->item(0);
$address1 = $address1->firstChild;
$address1_val = $address1->textContent;
```